# GWT project in eclipse: Cannot resolve objects of gFlot library

Tags: eclipse, gwt, flot

I downloaded gflot for my gwt project. To get to know the library I created a test project called "FlotDemo". I'm using Eclipse and created a plain vanilla gwt project with the help of the project creation wizard (the stuff with the greeting servlet and so on)

This is what I did:

1. Downloaded gflot-3.1.1.jar and copied it into /war/WEB-INF/lib
2. Added in Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries gflot-jar to the path
3. Added `<inherits name="com.googlecode.gflot.GFlot"/>` to my "FlotDemo.gwt.xml"
4. Went to [gFlot example](http://gflot2.appspot.com/#line:filename=LineExample&rawSource=false) and copy an pasted it to my EntryPoint class

So, after that my eclipse code looks something like in the following picture:
[image]

As you can see, eclipse is not able to resolve the objects in the library. When I start the app and try to access it under http://'127.0.0.1:8888'/FlotDemo.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] [flotdemo] - Validating units:
[TRACE] [flotdemo] - Finding entry point classes
    [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Errors in 'file:/Users/Tom/MeineDaten/Java/FlotDemo/src/flotdemo/client/FlotDemo.java'
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 15: SimplePlot cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 15: No source code is available for type SimplePlot; did you forget to inherit a required module?
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 20: Widget cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 20: No source code is available for type Widget; did you forget to inherit a required module?
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 22: PlotModel cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 22: PlotModel cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 23: PlotOptions cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 23: PlotOptions cannot be resolved
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 24: LegendOptions cannot be resolved
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 25: LegendPosition cannot be resolved
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 26: GridOptions cannot be resolved
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 29: SimplePlot cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 29: SimplePlot cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] [flotdemo] - Line 42: UiHandler cannot be resolved to a type
            ....and so on...
```

What is wrong here?

UPDATE: The classpath should not make any problems. Have look at the following screenshots:
[image: The left part is the package explorer and the right is the class path configuration]

The left part is the package explorer and the right is the class path configuration

I think this should be right. At least I do not see an error here. So what else could it be?

Okay, I think I know now what the problem is. I had a look into the MANIFEST.MF file. There I can find the following entry:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Nico
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
```

So, since I'm running with Java 1.6 this should be the reason for the problem. BUT, there is no compiled version for Java 1.6. How can I compile the source into a JAR file?

Comment: Is the library in your class path?  You can add it with the build path menu option on the project.

Comment: You have your project in RED so take a look to Markers and post errors here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical case of a class-path issue in your project.

Although your setup seems to be ok (including the 3party library in your classpath and inheriting the gflot module in your gwt.xml file), it seems there are more things going on: for instance your eclipse is underlining in red `Widget` which is in the gwt sdk.

So first be sure that your eclipse setup is correct, you shouldn't have any line in red. Then be sure that all 3party source files are in your classpath (this must already be true, since all gwt libraries include sources in the .jar artifact).

Update:
Your project is in red, check what is happening. You must have some errors in the Markers tab.